# How can I replicate Google Page Speed's lossless image compression as part of my workflow?

Tags: images, optimization, page-speed

I love that Google's Page Speed is able to losslessly compress a lot of my images, but I'd love to make it part of my workflow, prior to uploading a site and making it live.

Is there anything I can run locally to give me the same lossless compression? I currently export images from Export For Web from Photoshop, and use a little application called PNGCrusher to reduce file size of PNGs.

I'd love to find a faster way though than saving out and replacing the individual images from Page Speed's results.

Comment: Doesn't `mod_pagespeed` already do this for you? Or are you unable to use the apache module? If so, you can use `mod_deflate` to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the Google Page Speed extension for Firefox, then a copy of the optimized images (as well as JavaScript and CSS files) are put in a temporary folder.

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/using_firefox.html#advanced

[image: Google Page Speed extension for Firefox]

You can then take these out, cleanup the file names, and reuse them.

[Download Google Page Speed extension for Firefox](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html)

Comment: I'm actually using PageSpeed in Chrome. I doesn't look like Chrome does that.

Comment: @Keefer you seem to be right...not sure why they wouldn't do this. Not a big problem for me, i use Chrome for day-to-day browsing, and Firefox for dev, as although Chrome is faster in general, Firefox still has a better range of extensions for developers, IMO.

Comment: Can someone confirm that the Firefox version stopped working?

Answer (score 6):

For MacOSX [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com) optimizes the images. Internally it uses the same tools used by google page speed.

http://imageoptim.com

Comment: Why was this voted down? ImageOptim is FOSS, and you can bulk process images. And, as he stated, it uses the same techniques to compress images as PageSpeed: stripping out meta data and using Huffman tables to losslessly compress JPEGS, and for PNG it literally uses the same exact optimizer that PageSpeed uses (OptiPNG).

Comment: This does not seem to be true (anymore?), as Pagespeed reports optimization possibilities for images that have previously been processed by Imageoptim to me.

Answer (score 5):

You could try http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/

Click "Uploader" and select all images that needs to be "smushed".

Your files will be uploaded to their server, become optimized without quality loss, and you will then be able to download all images in a zip file.

Comment: Really looking for a local application, though this may be a decent web-based solution to try.

Comment: Just thought I would mention that apparently Yahoo may have discontinued Smushit as a service. There are some alternatives out there available via web search.